# How to open the file explorer in android programatically?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, file-upload, ms-word

I am creating an application by which I can upload word/pdf file and sent it to a server. For that I want to open a file explorer where I can select Word/PDF file from my mobile and upload it to server via web service.
I have tried following code but its not working,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
try{
    startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "There are no file explorer clients installed.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? Or what happens instead?

Comment: i want to open file explorer but my above code open gallery , music and voice record option .

Comment: Try without the second line.

Comment: I have tried it, but It works only if there is External File explorer installed.

Comment: Of course. What did you expect else?

Comment: i dont want to install external file explorer.

Comment: i want to open built-in file explorer using intent

Comment: What do you consider the 'built-in file explorer`? Build in what?

Comment: built-in means default explorer of device.

Comment: That's what i thought already. The question remains the same 'What do you consider to be the default explorer of the device?'.

Comment: "my files" in android devices

Comment: my files??? If you want help you should take some more effort to explain what you want or have. This makes no fun.

Comment: i am working on a project in which i want to upload doc/pdf file which is reside in my sdcard. so how to access pdf/doc file from  android activity.

Comment: i need a functionality which is available while we attach mail in gmail(Android application).

Comment: `my files???`. So no effort to make that clear!?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below updated code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
try{
    startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "There are no file explorer clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("path"); //  directory path
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```